# Combing multiple csv files from multiple subfolders in one folder

Tags: python, merge

Im trying to combine multiple files located in a directory. Each of the the files is located 3 subfolders(each subfolder has another folder or file) down from the main folder and I am unable to combine all of them. The best I can do is combine the ones in each bottom most subfolder. I can get a list of every specific file I want to combine from scanning but I can't combine them. I've gone through several methods and tutorials and can't find a way to do this. The code I have is below:

```
import pandas as pd
import os
import glob
os.getcwd()

path_of_the_directory = 'C:\\Users\\user\\Downloads\\top_folder'
ext = ('.csv')
for files in os.listdir(path_of_the_directory):
    if files.endswith(ext):
        print(files)  
    else:
        continue

def list_files(dir):
    r = []
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(dir):
        for name in files:
            filepath = root + os.sep + name
            if filepath.endswith(".csv"):
                r.append(os.path.join(root, name))
    return r
    print(r)
    files = []
    for file in r:
        #for dir, dir_name, file_list in os.walk(path):
        files.append(os.path.join(path,file))
        

    combined_df = pd.concat([pd.read_csv(file) for file in files])
    df = pd.concat([pd.read_csv(f) for f in files])

    df.to_csv("merged.csv")
print(files)
list_files(data_dir)

data_dir = r'C:\\Users\\user\\Downloads\top_folder'
sub_folders = os.listdir(data_dir)
sub_folders

path = os.path.join(data_dir, sub_folders[2])

os.chdir(path)
files = glob.glob(path + ".\*\*.csv")
files

df = pd.concat([pd.read_csv(f) for f in chat_files])

df.to_csv("merged.csv")
```

Any help or direction would be extremely appreciated.

Comment: What does glob.glob yield? In the end you're not using that. I experienced glob.glob to be one of the better gathers.

Comment: Nothing. I tried using it but couldnt get it to combine all the files down. The best I could get was combining the files from within each individual subfolder at a time